# Is there a macro to detect the operating system...?

Tags: windows, winapi, visual-c++, windows-7, ms-media-foundation

I am planning to write a piece of code using the media foundation API which is available after vista. I want to add the code inside a #if block something like...

```
#if <SomeMacro>
// all the classes using MediaFoundation go here.
#endif
```

I could not find a macro to detect the operating system version. How is this normally done on windows?? I found _WIN32 and _WIN64 to detect 32-bit and 64-bit but no macros to determine api availability. Is there a better way of isolating code based on API availability in vc..?

Thanks,
Abhinay.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, here they are:
[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383745(VS.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383745%28VS.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Not really.  The best you can do is to key off the WIN32_WINNT macro, but that doesn't help you if someone turns around and tries to run your application on XP.

Answer (score 1):

Try the `_WIN32_WINNT` and `WINVER` macros.  More info here:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383745%28VS.85%29.aspx

Try something like,

```
#ifdef _WIN32_WINNT_VISTA
    #if WINVER >= _WIN32_WINNT_VISTA
        //....
    #endif
#endif
```